# Include PHP functions in where clause?

Tags: mysql

I want to use `floorRating` in the WHERE clause but I get error: `Unknown column in where clause`.

```
SELECT ID,
floor(SUM(Rating) / COUNT(*)) AS `floorRating`
FROM `Reviews` 
WHERE floorRating = 1
GROUP BY `ID`
```

I also tried this but didn't work:

```
SELECT ID,
FROM `Reviews` 
WHERE floor(SUM(Rating) / COUNT(*)) = 1
GROUP BY `ID`
```

In this I get `Invalid use of group function`.

How can I get this type of query to work?

Comment: 1 should be an int not string (from the looks of it), and you can use `HAVING` instead of where though it isn't as performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be any PHP functions, it must be a MYSQL one. You're lucky, because floor exists too.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor

When `where` doesn't work, try `having`.

```
HAVING floorRating = 1
```

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that you're trying to use the MySQL function `FLOOR`, it's that you can't use a column alias in your `WHERE` clause (though you can't use a PHP function in MySQL - it's a different language).

This is because the `WHERE` clause is evaluated **before** your `SELECT`s and other statements, meaning it knows what rows to work with before anything else (to simplify).

You need to use `HAVING` instead in these cases, which *will* work.